# Passing JSON as part of an object to .net core API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The API I am working on requires a very complicated JSON object be passed in as a string, along with other values. So I created a class like this:

```
public class BURequest
{       
    public Guid  ID { get; set; }
    public string JSONStr { get; set; }  --->JSON passed in as string
    public string VersionName { get; set; }
}
```

The API controller has the following method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Check ([FromBody] BURequest testRequest)
```

However I kept getting "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: c. Path 'BURequest', line 4, position 3."

Here is the JSON string:

```
  {
      "content_version": "1",
      "date_created": "2020-10-06T13:52:15.288Z",
      "date_updated": "2020-10-06T13:54:24.325Z",
      "tools": {
        "car": true,
        "truck": true
      }
   }
```

Is there any way to get around this problem without having to create a class for the JSON object itself? It's a complicated object and has a huge number of properties. Thanks!

p.s.I've verified that the JSON string is valid using JSONLint as suggested below.

Comment: Use `dynamic` or `Dictionary<>` to for that property, or use `dynamic` for the request type

Comment: Thanks! But if I use dynamic either for the property or for the request, I got the same error message (i.e. unexpected char encountered). If I use dictionary for the property, I got 'Error converting value \"{\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'.

Comment: You could plug the entire request body into a tool like https://jsonlint.com/ to establish whether the problem is with the serialization or the de-serialization and include that info in the question. Also try changing JSONStr  from a string to a JObject.

Comment: If none of that works, you may need to escape all the json special characters before making the request.

Comment: Thanks @Connell.O'Donnell. I tried using JObject and it worked!

Comment: bad idea. even if you manage to do it your code will end up being inefficient and unmaintainable. it will not be clear what's in that json string at any time. do the legwork and create a class

Answer (score 1):

I would use JsonElement for this:

```
public class BURequest
{       
    public Guid  ID { get; set; }
    public JsonElement JSONStr { get; set; }  --->JSON passed in as string
    public string VersionName { get; set; }
}
```

And then just get the value:

```
testRequest.JSONStr.ToString()
```

The Json needs to be:

```
{
    "JSONStr" : {
      "content_version": "1",
      "date_created": "2020-10-06T13:52:15.288Z",
      "date_updated": "2020-10-06T13:54:24.325Z",
      "tools": {
        "car": true,
        "truck": true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but the validator for the request was complaining about an empty JSONStr.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how the Json needs to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an answer to go with the comment on the question. Changing the type of the `JSONStr`  property from `string` to `JObject` solves the problem.